# 3 column CSS - middle column drops down in IE7

Tags: css

I have a problem with what seems a straight forward 3 column in CSS. Works fine in IE8 onwards but IE7 the middle column drops underneath the left and right columns. I've searched for solutions on google and here at stackoverflow already but no matter what I try it just either doesn't do anything or it breaks it in IE8 onwards. Ill be honest im not a master at programming so its my lack of understanding that's most likely the cause.

Thanks in advance

The CSS code

```
.wrap {
margin:0 auto;
width:850px;
}

#proleft {
float: left;
width: 245px;
padding-right:10px;
border-right-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#dddddd;
}

#procontent {
padding: 0 250px 0px 235px;
margin-left:40px;
margin-right:40px;
}

#proright {
padding-left: 10px;
float: right;
width: 250px;
border-left-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#dddddd;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="wrap">

<div id="proleft">
CONTENT
</div>  

<div id="proright">
CONTENT 
</div>  

<div id="procontent">
CONTENT
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>           

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried making the middle column a bit smaller (width-wise) to see if it's simply too large in IE7? You may need some IE7-specific styling to ensure it's not too large.

Comment: the padding sums to the width. A column 250px width with a padding left 10px would be rendered as 260px. the sum of the columns, plus paddings plus margins is grater than the container

Comment: How embarrassing, Ateszki/James you're absolutely right. I didn't even see that. I've lowered the numbers and its worked. Thank you because ive been looking at that code for hours!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way 
http://tinkerbin.com/cZNxkKK8

css

```
.wrap {
margin:0 auto;
width:850px;
}

#proleft {
float: left;
width: 250px;
padding: 0;
border-right-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#dddddd;
}

#procontent {
float: left;
padding: 0 40px;
}

#proright {
padding: 0;
float: right;
width: 250px;
border-left-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#dddddd;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

html

```
<div class="wrap">

<div id="proleft">
CONTENT
</div>  

<div id="procontent">
CONTENT
</div>

<div id="proright">
CONTENT 
</div>  

<div class="clear"></div>           

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's NOT exactly the solution for your answer. But this code gets the result that you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/mXnS5/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hey</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="proleft">

        </div>

        <div id="proright">

        </div>
        <div id="procontent">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#wrap {
margin:0 auto;
width:850px;
}

#wrap > div {
height:300px;
}

#proleft { float:left; width:245px; background-color:#CCC; }
#proright { float:right; width:245px; background-color:#DDD;}
#procontent { margin-left:245px; margin-right:245px; background-color:#EEE;}
```